# How to fix this issue where require('./<path to json from working directory>') is throwing ERROR: Cannot find module './<path to json>'?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I am requiring the JSON file to a variable using require(./).

Here I am testing a webpage where I am using wdio test runner.

The project directory structure is like this

```
practiseWebdriver.io/
    /test --> contains test Scripts
    /pageobjects --> contains json file to be read
```

When tried to use:

`var pageObject = require('./pageobjects/abc.json');`

I am facing error -> `ERROR: Cannot find module './pageobjects/abc.json'`

But the script is running fine when I try :

`1. var pageObject = require('/home/{user}/Documents/VS_Workspace/practiseWebdriver.io/pageobjects/abc.json');
2. var pageObject = require(process.cwd()+'./pageobjects/abc.json');`

Can you please help me to identify if there's anything I am missing?

Comment: the folder is `pageobjects` (according to your "structure") but the error shows `PageObjects` - that looks *odd* to begin with

Comment: sorry, typo occurred while generalizing. Updated this.

Answer (score 0):

use this : require('../pageobjects/abc.json');

Comment: Thanks!! This worked. I was having a feeling that I was missing something.